# Out of gas error for a view function

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, gas, out-of-gas

having a problem with calling a method of my deployed contract in the main Ethereum network.

I have a 'view' function which returns user's refund balance, everything worked fine in my local blockchain (Ganache), but doesn't work in the main network :(

So here I call that method from web3:

```
this.myContract.methods.checkFunds().call().then((refunds) => {
      return refunds;
});
```

this is my contract function and here I call another contract function:

```
mapping(address => uint256) private funds;

function checkFunds() external view returns(uint256) {
    return contract2.checkFunds(msg.sender);
}
```

here is that contract2:

```
function checkFunds(address _owner) public view returns(uint256) {
    return funds[_owner];
}
```

if user doesn't have funds then it should return 0 and it's uint256, then it should be ok, but I get such an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
at ABICoder.decodeParameters (app.js:37038)
at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (app.js:36366)
at Method.outputFormatter (app.js:36719)
at Method.formatOutput (app.js:9201)
at sendTxCallback (app.js:9511)
at app.js:96628
at inpage.js:1
at inpage.js:1
at o (inpage.js:1)
at inpage.js:1
```

and I have the latest version of web3 btw:`"react-web3": "1.2.0",`

Do view functions cost gas ? That's strange, because I call another method of that contract to read items and it doesn't cost anything.

thank you!

Comment: The error printout is misleading (you), because a `view` function does not require any gas in order to execute it. It is merely a "peek" into the blockchain data (i.e., no mining is performed).

Comment: I suggest that in your contract, check if `contract2` is initialized correctly.

Comment: @goodvibration thank you for your reply. It's also in the main network and I have already tried to call it's functions, so the problem in this one only. Checked it in etherscan, it's also there, so that function exists and it's view one there

Comment: Make sure that you are calling the function `checkFunds()` other contract, not of contract2.

Comment: Well, is `contract2` deployed on the main network?

Comment: @MaheshRajput I equally named them, so it shouldn't be a problem and I use an address of the that other contract, not contract2

Comment: @goodvibration yeah, but I renamed everything just not to waste your time reading a long camelcase function names.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a `call()`, without setting the `msg.sender`. Try to [add the `addr` as a param to the `checkFunds()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847788/msg-sender-does-not-work-inside-a-view-function-why-is-there-a-workaround), modify the web3 call accordingly and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.myContract.methods.checkFunds().call({
  from: 0x123...
}).then((refunds) => {
  return refunds;
});
```

input address in call()